# CMake: automatically generate c-wrapper file from cpp-file

Tags: c++, cmake, build-automation

For some reasons I have quite a few functions of a shared library written in C++ that have to be "wrapped" by a C-function to be called correctly. Now, I wonder if I can automate this process (at best well integrated into my CMake-build-process)

An example: Suppose I have the function definition

```
extern "C" void foo(Somestruct myinfo, char const * const data, char const * const data2)
```

in my .hpp-file. Now I would alter this definition to, say

```
C_WRAPPER void foo(Somestruct myinfo, ARG(1) data, ARG(3) data2)
```

Using some macros, this can be converted to the original form without any problems - thus, leaving the hpp-file untouched from a functional point of view.

Some parser now should read this file and produce a new c-file that contains (for example)

```
extern void foo(Somestruct myinfo, char const * const, char const*const);
void foo_wrapper(Array everything) {
     char * data1 = fromArray(array, 1);
     char * data3 = fromArray(arary, 3);
     foo(fromArray(0), data1, data3);
}
```

Boundary conditions: The general layout always looks the same. The only difference is that the number of `ARG`s is necessarily constant. The arguments of `ARG` give the position in the array the data is located.

Currently the wrapper file is written manually, which resulted in some time-consuming errors due to interface changes in the past. That is the reason I would like to automate this step.

Do you know a way to archive something like this without having to create a parser myself? As said, preferably something that fits well into my build process using CMake.

Answer (score 1):

I have the honor of answering my own question.
It can be done entirely in CMake.

Here just the CMake script that fills a variable `funcstring` that contains all wrapper functions. Using a typical configure-file, those strings may be written in the wrapper function.

```
set(sources a.cpp)

foreach(source ${sources})
    file(READ ${source} contents)

    foreach(var IN ITEMS ${contents})
        string(REGEX MATCH "C_WRAPPER[ ]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+[(].*[)]" wrapperfun ${var})

        if(wrapperfun)
        string(REGEX REPLACE "C_WRAPPER[ ]+\([a-zA-Z0-9]+\)[(].*[)]" "\\1" function_name ${wrapperfun})

        string(REGEX MATCHALL "ARG[(][0-9]+[)]" args ${wrapperfun})

        set(lines "")
        set(funcargs "")
        foreach(arg ${args})
            string(REGEX MATCH "[0-9]+" num ${arg})
            set(lines "${lines}
                char * data${num} = fromArray(array, ${num})\;")
            set(funcargs "${funcargs}, arg${num})")
        endforeach(arg)

        set(funcstring "
            ${wrapperfun}\;
            Datum ${function_name}_wrapper(Array everything) {
                ${lines}
                return ${function_name}(fromArray(0), ${funcargs})\;
            }

        ")

        endif()    

    endforeach(var)
endforeach(source)
```

The macros have not been replaced - this could be done in CMake, but it is shorter and more straightforward to include adequate macro defines in the final C-file.